# generate SQL query in Pentaho report designer with parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, pentaho-report-designer

I created two parameters named `id` and `task_name` in Pentaho report designer. Display type of both of them are drop down. When I am trying to change the query based on the parameters I didn't get any data in the drop-down. But the data of the drop-down display when I do not edit the query with parameters My query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_project_tasks 
WHERE id = ${id}
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In the parameter you'll find a field named **Query**.
This query should not be the main query mentioned above.
You should create a new query in which you only select the *id* from your data base. Name it *idparameter* for example. It goes like this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM tbl_project_tasks
```

Now in the parameter select *idparameter* in **Query**, *id* in **Value** and *id* in **Display Name**.
Make sure that the name of the parameter in **Name** is the same as the one in the **${}** in the main query.

Hope that was the answer for your question.